# How to evaluate autoencoder performance by mse?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I want to train autoencoder on mnist dataset to generate images similar to input. That's code I found:

```
% Load the training data. 
XTrain = digitTrainCellArrayData;


%% 
% Train an autoencoder with a hidden layer containing 50 neurons. 
hiddenSize = 50;
autoenc = trainAutoencoder(XTrain,hiddenSize,...
        'MaxEpochs', 200, ...
        'L2WeightRegularization', 10^(-3),...
        'SparsityRegularization',1,...
        'SparsityProportion',0.45);  

% Load the test data. 
XTest = digitTestCellArrayData; 

% Reconstruct the test image data using the trained autoencoder. 
xReconstructed = predict(autoenc, XTest);
```

And now I want to somehow evaluate performance of my autoencoder and I'm not sure how to do it. I found [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/trainautoencoder.html) that MSE can be used between real and reconstructed data set. However when I tried this:

```
mse(XTest - xReconstructed)
```

I obtain error

```
Operator '-' is not supported for operands of type 'cell'.
```

How can I properly perform evaluation of this autoencoder using mse?

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two kind of metrics/loss function in generative models/image restoration models

1. reference based

   - l2 loss (~rmse loss)
   - l1 loss
   - PSNR : peak Signal-to-Noise ratio
2. non-reference based

   - SSIM : structural similarity index,
   - MS-SSIM : Multi-scale SSIM

     *Also there are metrics that are combination of both of classes (Ex. Mixed SM-SSIM)
     For more detailed understanding you can read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08861.pdf).

I think for the error you got can be resolve by,
`mse(vec1, vec2)`
*It could also depends on library you are using.